# How to return the value of a function after button click in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, anonymous-function, inappbrowser

I have a function which returns the output to a promise function when called.

I have a executeScript Method, which dynamically processes Javascript methods and returns a promise as to what those methods return.

**Base Skeleton**

```
Ref.executeScript({
                code: "getData(); function getData(){ var res = 'Hello'; return res;}",
            function(results){
     console.log(results); ////THIS RETURNS "Hello"
   });
```

When the code is directly returning a variable it works. For example, the following returns Hello when executed.

```
getData();
 function getData(){
   var res = "Hello";
   return res;
  }
```

But if I return it inside the click event, it returns the previous value "Hello"
and not "Hello2" on button click. I want "Hello2" to be returned.

```
getData();
function getData(){
 var res = "Hello";
 jQuery("#myButton").on('click', function(){
   res = "Hello2";
   alert(res); //this gets called
  });
return res;
}
```

Updated the Original question to provide more clarity

Comment: Should `getData()` await the dispatch of `.on()` before returning a value? _"But if i return it inside the click event, it returns the previous value "Hello" and not "Hello2" on button click. I want "Hello2" to be returned."_ No value is `return`ed from inside `click` handler.

Comment: try use  return statement inside click callback function

Comment: @guest271314 yes, i want getData() to wait for the on event to complete. It should only return when button click updates the model

Comment: what is **myButton** ? class or id of button ?

Comment: @SouravDas You can use `jQuery.Deferred` to return a jQuery promise object, or use built-in `new Promise()` constructor to resolve a value after `click` event is dispatched, then chain `.then()` with a function passed as parameter where the argument is the fulfilled jQuery promise or `Promise` value.

Comment: All your function does with `jQuery('#myButton').on(...)` is establish a click event listener on your `#myButton` element. You should have that listener execute the required statements as they will only happen when you **click** on the element

Comment: @Phil, i need to return the value calculated on the click event back to the main function

Comment: It's unlikely that you actually _"need"_ that. You should explain what is meant to happen and when, keeping in mind that any click event will be fired long after `getData()` has completed executing.

Comment: @guest271314 and others, i have updated my question to have a better understanding now.Apologies for the confusion

Comment: Is `.executeScript()` used in a Chromium/Chrome extension?

Comment: You are trying to get changed value of `res` which is local when you are registering it for event. `res` in anonymous function and `getData()` are different hence you are not getting the output you want. Global variables would solve the problem but they are not a good programming practices.

Comment: @guest271314, yes its used in InAppbrowser plugin for cordova

Comment: @SouravDas The [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/#inappbrowserexecutescript) does not appear to mention handling asynchronous processes for `details` _"If the injected script is of type code, the callback executes with a single parameter, which is the return value of the script, wrapped in an Array.."_ Though this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37479349/2801559) states that `.executeScript()` is a `Promise` where `.then()` can be chained.

Comment: @guest271314 you are correct, the alert works, but i am not getting the value in the then if it gets triggered inside a button click

Comment: @SouravDas Have not tried Cordova InAppBrowser, untested `function getData() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    jQuery("#myButton").on('click', function() {
      resolve("Hello2")
    })
  })
}`

Comment: @SouravDas See also https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/issues/279. Have you considered filing an issue to ask what the suggested approach is for using asynchronous code at `.executeScript()`?

Comment: @guest271314 saw that.tried that. didn't work. but we are just returning a small string in this case.
I will raise the issue there. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188011/discussion-between-sourav-das-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 0):

Of course it still returns "Hello", because when you call that function it does not enter on the click function. What your function really does is setting an action for the click event, but not also calling it.
You can't really return a value in a click event function and I can't imagine where would you need it.
You can try with out of scope variables like this but I don't recommend doing it:

```
var hasBeenClicked = false;
jQuery("myButton").on('click', function(){ 
     hasBeenClicked = true;
});

function buttonWasClicked() {
     var res = hasBeenClicked;
     hasBeenClicked = false;
     return res;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you should write something like that:

```
var res = '';
function getData(){
    res = "Hello";
    return res;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myButton").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault(); //if you have form to submit
       res = "Hello2";
    });
});
```

Comment: By clicking in the button that have id='myButton' the value of res will be 'Hello2'

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to updated value on click event for this you have to use javascript prototype try this

```
function GetData(){
   this.res = "Hello";

} 
jQuery("#myButton").on('click', function(){

   GetData.prototype.res = "Hello2";
     alert(res); //this gets called
  });
  getData  = new GetData();
  console.log (getData.res)
```